# Join two tables and filter to retrieve Name

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

This code is performing well as expected.

```
var soldQtyForEachItem = await _context.InvoiceProduct
    .Where(x => x.ProductId != 0)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
    .Select(grp => new CompanyProducts 
    { 
        CompanyProductId = grp.Key, 
        CompanyProductSoldQuantity = grp.Sum(item => item.QuantitySold)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

**Question :**

I now need to join another table called **Products** and filter by Id against InvoiceProduct table and retrieve
ProductsItemName which is a row from Products table; then all need to go to a custom type "CompanyProducts" below.

*Please how do I achieve it?*

---

```
public class CompanyProducts
{
    public int CompanyProductId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyProductName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyProductSoldQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

InvoiceProduct table is a many to many, meaning that one InvoiceId may have multiple ProductIds.

Products table has property like ProductId, ProductsItemName.

Comment: hi mate, you forgot to ask a question. What is it exactly that you have difficulties with?

Comment: @MongZhu  Thank you for trying to help me. I just edited the post to clearly show the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solutions is to include `ProductItemName` into grouping:

```cs
var soldQtyForEachItem =  await _context.InvoiceProduct
    .Where(x => x.ProductId != 0)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductId, x.Product.ProductsItemName } )
    .Select(grp => new CompanyProducts 
    { 
        CompanyProductId = grp.Key.ProductId, 
        CompanyProductName = grp.Key.ProductsItemName,
        CompanyProductSoldQuantity = grp.Sum(item => item.QuantitySold)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.